# Persist annotation works only value Strategy Client . Tapestry application

Tags: tapestry

Hi i am a new tapestry learner. I had a hard time learning @Persist.
@Persist annotation only works with Strategy Client value `@Persist(PersistenceConstants.CLIENT)`. 
if I try to use other strategies like `@Persist`, `@Persist(PersistenceConstants.FLASH)`, an error occurs.

*and Also  `@SessionState` annotation doesn’t work either. I think both problems may be stemming from the same thing. So when I manage to use the first `@Persist`, `@SessionState` will work too*

**Start.java**

```
@Property @Persist
private Integer randomNumber;

 void onNextRandom() {
        randomNumber = new Random().nextInt();    
    }
```

**Start.tml**

```
<html xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_0_0.xsd" >

...

<div>Random number: ${randomNumber}</div>
<div><a id="generate" t:type="eventlink" event="nextRandom">Generate next random</a></div>

...

</html>
```

**AppModule.java**

```
package com.example.simple.services;

import org.apache.tapestry5.SymbolConstants;
import org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.MappedConfiguration;
import org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.OrderedConfiguration;
import org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.ServiceBinder;
import org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.annotations.Contribute;
import org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.annotations.Local;
import org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.services.ApplicationDefaults;
import org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.services.SymbolProvider;
import org.apache.tapestry5.services.Request;
import org.apache.tapestry5.services.RequestFilter;
import org.apache.tapestry5.services.RequestHandler;
import org.apache.tapestry5.services.Response;
import org.slf4j.Logger;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.UUID;

/**
 * This module is automatically included as part of the Tapestry IoC Registry, it's a good place to
 * configure and extend Tapestry, or to place your own service definitions.
 */
public class AppModule
{
    public static void bind(ServiceBinder binder)
    {
        // binder.bind(MyServiceInterface.class, MyServiceImpl.class);

        // Make bind() calls on the binder object to define most IoC services.
        // Use service builder methods (example below) when the implementation
        // is provided inline, or requires more initialization than simply
        // invoking the constructor.
    }

    public static void contributeFactoryDefaults(MappedConfiguration<String, Object> configuration)
    {
        // The values defined here (as factory default overrides) are themselves
        // overridden with application defaults by DevelopmentModule and QaModule.

        // The application version is primarily useful as it appears in
        // any exception reports (HTML or textual).
        configuration.override(SymbolConstants.APPLICATION_VERSION, "1.0-SNAPSHOT");

        // This is something that should be removed when going to production, but is useful
        // in the early stages of development.
        configuration.override(SymbolConstants.PRODUCTION_MODE, false);
    }

    public static void contributeApplicationDefaults(MappedConfiguration<String, Object> configuration)
    {
        // Contributions to ApplicationDefaults will override any contributions to
        // FactoryDefaults (with the same key). Here we're restricting the supported
        // locales to just "en" (English). As you add localised message catalogs and other assets,
        // you can extend this list of locales (it's a comma separated series of locale names;
        // the first locale name is the default when there's no reasonable match).
        configuration.add(SymbolConstants.SUPPORTED_LOCALES, "en");

        configuration.add(SymbolConstants.SESSION_LOCKING_ENABLED, true);
        // You should change the passphrase immediately; the HMAC passphrase is used to secure
        // the hidden field data stored in forms to encrypt and digitally sign client-side data.
        configuration.add(SymbolConstants.HMAC_PASSPHRASE, "change this immediately-" + UUID.randomUUID());
    }

    /**
     * Use annotation or method naming convention: <code>contributeApplicationDefaults</code>
     */
    @Contribute(SymbolProvider.class)
    @ApplicationDefaults
    public static void setupEnvironment(MappedConfiguration<String, Object> configuration)
    {
        // Support for jQuery is new in Tapestry 5.4 and will become the only supported
        // option in 5.5.
        configuration.add(SymbolConstants.JAVASCRIPT_INFRASTRUCTURE_PROVIDER, "jquery");
        configuration.add(SymbolConstants.BOOTSTRAP_ROOT, "context:mybootstrap");
    }


    /**
     * This is a service definition, the service will be named "TimingFilter". The interface,
     * RequestFilter, is used within the RequestHandler service pipeline, which is built from the
     * RequestHandler service configuration. Tapestry IoC is responsible for passing in an
     * appropriate Logger instance. Requests for static resources are handled at a higher level, so
     * this filter will only be invoked for Tapestry related requests.
     *
     *
     * Service builder methods are useful when the implementation is inline as an inner class
     * (as here) or require some other kind of special initialization. In most cases,
     * use the static bind() method instead.
     *
     *
     * If this method was named "build", then the service id would be taken from the
     * service interface and would be "RequestFilter".  Since Tapestry already defines
     * a service named "RequestFilter" we use an explicit service id that we can reference
     * inside the contribution method.
     */
    public RequestFilter buildTimingFilter(final Logger log)
    {
        return new RequestFilter()
        {
            public boolean service(Request request, Response response, RequestHandler handler)
            throws IOException
            {
                long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                try
                {
                    // The responsibility of a filter is to invoke the corresponding method
                    // in the handler. When you chain multiple filters together, each filter
                    // received a handler that is a bridge to the next filter.

                    return handler.service(request, response);
                } finally
                {
                    long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;

                    log.info("Request time: {} ms", elapsed);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    /**
     * This is a contribution to the RequestHandler service configuration. This is how we extend
     * Tapestry using the timing filter. A common use for this kind of filter is transaction
     * management or security. The @Local annotation selects the desired service by type, but only
     * from the same module.  Without @Local, there would be an error due to the other service(s)
     * that implement RequestFilter (defined in other modules).
     */
    @Contribute(RequestHandler.class)
    public void addTimingFilter(OrderedConfiguration<RequestFilter> configuration,
        @Local RequestFilter filter)
    {
        // Each contribution to an ordered configuration has a name, When necessary, you may
        // set constraints to precisely control the invocation order of the contributed filter
        // within the pipeline.

        configuration.add("Timing", filter);
    }
}
```

**Error on Console**

```
2020-05-15 10:56:22,242 [qtp1011276990-21      ] ERROR                            org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.Registry java.lang.AbstractMethodError
2020-05-15 10:56:22,242 [qtp1011276990-21      ] ERROR                            org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.Registry Operations trace:
2020-05-15 10:56:22,242 [qtp1011276990-21      ] ERROR                            org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.Registry [ 1] Handling traditional 'nextrandom' component event request for Start.
2020-05-15 10:56:22,242 [qtp1011276990-21      ] ERROR                            org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.Registry [ 2] Triggering event 'nextrandom' on Start
2020-05-15 10:56:22,242 [qtp1011276990-21      ] ERROR che.tapestry5.modules.TapestryModule.RequestExceptionHandler Processing of request failed with uncaught exception: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: null
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.AbstractSessionManager.addSession(AbstractSessionManager.java:728) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.AbstractSessionManager.newHttpSession(AbstractSessionManager.java:589) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getSession(Request.java:1271) ~[?:?]
    at $HttpServletRequest_130978c37d822.getSession(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at $HttpServletRequest_130978c37d821.getSession(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.TapestrySessionFactoryImpl.getSession(TapestrySessionFactoryImpl.java:140) ~[tapestry-core-5.5.0.jar:?]
    at $TapestrySessionFactory_130978c37d81e.getSession(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.RequestImpl.getSession(RequestImpl.java:129) ~[tapestry-core-5.5.0.jar:?]
    at $Request_130978c37d8ab.getSession(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at $Request_130978c37d805.getSession(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.AbstractSessionPersistentFieldStrategy.postChange(AbstractSessionPersistentFieldStrategy.java:124) ~[tapestry-core-5.5.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.PersistentFieldManagerImpl.postChange(PersistentFieldManagerImpl.java:87) ~[tapestry-core-5.5.0.jar:?]
    at $PersistentFieldManager_130978c37d860.postChange(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.PageImpl.persistFieldChange(PageImpl.java:266) ~[tapestry-core-5.5.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.InternalComponentResourcesImpl.persistFieldChange(InternalComponentResourcesImpl.java:310) ~[tapestry-core-5.5.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.transform.PersistWorker$PersistentFieldConduit.set(PersistWorker.java:64) ~[tapestry-core-5.5.0.jar:?]
    at com.example.simple.pages.Start.conduit_set_randomNumber(Start.java) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.example.simple.pages.Start.onNextRandom(Start.java:54) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.example.simple.pages.Start.dispatchComponentEvent(Start.java) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.dispatchEvent(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:917) ~[tapestry-core-5.5.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.processEventTriggering(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:1102) ~[tapestry-core-5.5.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.access$3100(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:57) ~[tapestry-core-5.5.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl$5.invoke(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:1047) ~[tapestry-core-5.5.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl$5.invoke(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:1044) ~[tapestry-core-5.5.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:82) ~[tapestry-ioc-5.5.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:72) ~[tapestry-ioc-5.5.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1260) ~[tapestry-ioc-5.5.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementResourcesImpl.invoke(ComponentPageElementResourcesImpl.java:154) ~[tapestry-core-5.5.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl.triggerContextEvent(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:1043) ~[tapestry-core-5.5.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.ComponentEventRequestHandlerImpl.handle(ComponentEventRequestHandlerImpl.java:73) ~[tapestry-core-5.5.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.AjaxFilter.handle(AjaxFilter.java:42) ~[tapestry-core-5.5.0.jar:?]
    at $ComponentEventRequestHandler_130978c37d977.handle(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.upload.internal.services.UploadExceptionFilter.handle(UploadExceptionFilter.java:76) ~[tapestry-upload-5.5.0.jar:?]
    at $ComponentEventRequestHandler_130978c37d977.handle(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.modules.TapestryModule$37.handle(TapestryModule.java:2225) ~[tapestry-core-5.5.0.jar:?]
    at $ComponentEventRequestHandler_130978c37d977.handle(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at $ComponentEventRequestHandler_130978c37d836.handle(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.ComponentRequestHandlerTerminator.handleComponentEvent(ComponentRequestHandlerTerminator.java:43) ~[tapestry-core-5.5.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.DeferredResponseRenderer.handleComponentEvent(DeferredResponseRenderer.java:45) ~[tapestry-core-5.5.0.jar:?]
    at $ComponentRequestHandler_130978c37d838.handleComponentEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.InitializeActivePageName.handleComponentEvent(InitializeActivePageName.java:39) ~[tapestry-core-5.5.0.jar:?]
    at $ComponentRequestHandler_130978c37d838.handleComponentEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.RequestOperationTracker$1.perform(RequestOperationTracker.java:55) ~[tapestry-core-5.5.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.RequestOperationTracker$1.perform(RequestOperationTracker.java:52) ~[tapestry-core-5.5.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.perform(OperationTrackerImpl.java:110) ~[tapestry-ioc-5.5.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.perform(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:84) ~[tapestry-ioc-5.5.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.perform(RegistryImpl.java:1266) ~[tapestry-ioc-5.5.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.RequestOperationTracker.handleComponentEvent(RequestOperationTracker.java:47) ~[tapestry-core-5.5.0.jar:?]
    at $ComponentRequestHandler_130978c37d838.handleComponentEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at $ComponentRequestHandler_130978c37d831.handleComponentEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.ComponentEventDispatcher.dispatch(ComponentEventDispatcher.java:48) ~[tapestry-core-5.5.0.jar:?]
    at $Dispatcher_130978c37d833.dispatch(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at $Dispatcher_130978c37d828.dispatch(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.modules.TapestryModule$RequestHandlerTerminator.service(TapestryModule.java:305) ~[tapestry-core-5.5.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.RequestErrorFilter.service(RequestErrorFilter.java:26) [tapestry-core-5.5.0.jar:?]
    at $RequestHandler_130978c37d829.service(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.modules.TapestryModule$3.service(TapestryModule.java:848) [tapestry-core-5.5.0.jar:?]
    at $RequestHandler_130978c37d829.service(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.modules.TapestryModule$2.service(TapestryModule.java:838) [tapestry-core-5.5.0.jar:?]
    at $RequestHandler_130978c37d829.service(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.StaticFilesFilter.service(StaticFilesFilter.java:89) [tapestry-core-5.5.0.jar:?]
    at $RequestHandler_130978c37d829.service(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at com.example.simple.services.AppModule$1.service(AppModule.java:112) [classes/:?]
    at $RequestFilter_130978c37d823.service(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at $RequestHandler_130978c37d829.service(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.CheckForUpdatesFilter$2.invoke(CheckForUpdatesFilter.java:105) [tapestry-core-5.5.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.CheckForUpdatesFilter$2.invoke(CheckForUpdatesFilter.java:95) [tapestry-core-5.5.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.ConcurrentBarrier.withRead(ConcurrentBarrier.java:83) [tapestry-ioc-5.5.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.CheckForUpdatesFilter.service(CheckForUpdatesFilter.java:119) [tapestry-core-5.5.0.jar:?]
    at $RequestHandler_130978c37d829.service(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at $RequestHandler_130978c37d81d.service(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.modules.TapestryModule$HttpServletRequestHandlerTerminator.service(TapestryModule.java:256) [tapestry-core-5.5.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.upload.internal.services.MultipartServletRequestFilter.service(MultipartServletRequestFilter.java:45) [tapestry-upload-5.5.0.jar:?]
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_130978c37d81f.service(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.gzip.GZipFilter.service(GZipFilter.java:59) [tapestry-core-5.5.0.jar:?]
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_130978c37d81f.service(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.IgnoredPathsFilter.service(IgnoredPathsFilter.java:69) [tapestry-core-5.5.0.jar:?]
    at $HttpServletRequestFilter_130978c37d819.service(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_130978c37d81f.service(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.modules.TapestryModule$1.service(TapestryModule.java:798) [tapestry-core-5.5.0.jar:?]
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_130978c37d81f.service(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_130978c37d818.service(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.TapestryFilter.doFilter(TapestryFilter.java:166) [tapestry-core-5.5.0.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1476) [jetty-servlet-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501) [jetty-servlet-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137) [jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557) [jetty-security-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231) [jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086) [jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429) [jetty-servlet-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193) [jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020) [jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135) [jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255) [jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154) [jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116) [jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370) [jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494) [jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971) [jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033) [jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644) [jetty-http-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235) [jetty-http-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82) [jetty-server-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696) [jetty-io-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53) [jetty-io-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608) [jetty-util-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543) [jetty-util-8.1.16.v20140903.jar:8.1.16.v20140903]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_172]
2020-05-15 10:56:22,285 [qtp1011276990-21      ] WARN  rg.apache.tapestry5.modules.TapestryModule.ExceptionReporter Wrote exception report to file:/C:/Users/User/eclipse-workspace/simple/build/exceptions/2020-05-15/10/56/exception-20200515-105622-281.26.txt
2020-05-15 10:56:22,317 [qtp1011276990-21      ] INFO            com.example.simple.services.AppModule.TimingFilter Request time: 78 ms
2020-05-15 10:56:22,933 [qtp1011276990-25      ] INFO            com.example.simple.services.AppModule.TimingFilter Request time: 2 ms
2020-05-15 10:56:23,063 [qtp1011276990-22      ] INFO            com.example.simple.services.AppModule.TimingFilter Request time: 2 ms
2020-05-15 10:56:23,066 [qtp1011276990-20      ] INFO            com.example.simple.services.AppModule.TimingFilter Request time: 1 ms
2020-05-15 10:56:23,074 [qtp1011276990-21      ] INFO            com.example.simple.services.AppModule.TimingFilter Request time: 4 ms
2020-05-15 10:56:23,086 [qtp1011276990-24      ] INFO            com.example.simple.services.AppModule.TimingFilter Request time: 2 ms
2020-05-15 10:56:23,092 [qtp1011276990-25      ] INFO            com.example.simple.services.AppModule.TimingFilter Request time: 2 ms
2020-05-15 10:56:23,146 [qtp1011276990-22      ] INFO            com.example.simple.services.AppModule.TimingFilter Request time: 1 ms
2020-05-15 10:56:23,166 [qtp1011276990-23      ] INFO            com.example.simple.services.AppModule.TimingFilter Request time: 0 ms
```

Comment: Your code works ok on my system. Telling from the stack trace, it may be a Jetty related problem. Were the last 9 lines of the console output generated by triggering the nextRandom event, without an error?

Comment: yes.if you look at the times when the errors occurred, they all occurred at the same time

Comment: Could this problem be caused by the browser or windows 10 firewall, windows 10 defenders